# Как просканировать сеть на наличие включенных компьютеров?

Tags: c++, linux, ip, lan

В локальных сетях есть компьютеры и у каждого из них есть свой IP адрес. Как узнать, перебирая все IP, какие компьютеры покдлюченны в сеть.

Я пробовал через комманду PING, получал от из нее ответ и проверял его:

```
string subNet = "192.168.1.";
for(int i = 1; i < 256; i++){
    string network_IP = subNet + to_string(i);
    string request = "ping " + network_IP + " -c 1 > /dev/null"; 
    string result = system(request.c_str()) == 0 ? "true" : "false";
    cout << network_IP << " available: " << result << endl;
}
```

но данная система работает очень долго, как можно это ускорить?

Comment: например, скопировать нужный кусок из исходников nmap-а.

Comment: Boost acio, Poco, Winapi. Список можно продолжать до бесконечности. Почитайте про icmp.

Comment: В общем случае никак.

Comment: Изучите вопрос, что такое ARP и как пользоваться утилитой `arping`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> система работает очень долго

она не **работает**. она **ждёт** ответа на ping-запрос. Если данный хост "живой", то ответ прилетает практически мгновенно. Если же хост не отвечает, то утилита *ping* ждёт таймаут. Величина этого таймаута задаётся ключиком "-W". Попробуйте задать "-W1" - посмотрите результат.

> как можно это ускорить?

Насчёт таймаута я уже сказал. Но, это не радикальное средство.  А радикальым решением будет написание двух функций:

1. Отправить ICMP-запрос
2. Ждать ответа на ICMP запрос.

Тогда Вы в цикле отправляете запросы по всем адресам локальной сети - без(!) ожидания ответа. Внутри каждого отправленного ICMP запроса указываете его ID.

После чего ждёте таймаут один(!) раз. Здесь цикл вызова второй вашей функции. Она принимает пакет и по ID определяет, от кого этот ответ пришёл. Всё это продолжается таймаут. Кто успел прислать ответ - тот живой. Кто не прислал - того нет в сети. Таким образом, таймаут отрабатывает только один раз.

Есть ещё одна проблема: сисадмины, для предотвращения хакинга, часто запрещают хостам отправлять ответы на ICMP запросы.

В качестве "рыбы" для написания этих двух функций рекомендую использовать простенький текст пользователя .failer на страничке  https://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=57566

Comment: Спасибо, попробую